# Add side panel without resizing parent

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I'm using `PySide2` to write a gui (witout QtDesigner).

The mainwindow contains plots and some other widgets. Through a menu option I want to open a side panel widget. The way I want it to work is that the whole window simply grows to contain that new widget without changing the size of anything else in the main window. How can this be done?

Currently the widget is just added to the central layout with `addWidget`, I've also tried making it a `QDockWidget` but it is still resized (and anyway I would like to avoid the extra fluff that comes with having a DockWidget).

So I have

```
    ---------
    |content|
    ---------
```

which should turn into

```
-------------
|new|content|
-------------
```

but currently I get

```
    ---------
    |new|cnt|
    ---------
```

Comment: What do you mean by Side Panel? You could put an image or scheme that illustrates what you want to get.

Comment: I'll try my hand at some ASCII sketches :P
But what I mean is this: I have a window and upon a button click I want to add new a widget to that window. This widget should appear on one of the sides but rather than fitting into the existing size, everything in the original window should stay the same size and the new widget should be placed in previously empty space next to original window.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do well on the "client" side of Qt; this would really belong within Qt itself. I have implemented a slightly more general variant of this a couple of years ago, and just to make it work well across Windows, Mac and KDE, the code ballooned to over a thousand lines to cover all the icky corner cases, with another thousand for the test harness. It was surprisingly hard to implement the tests - especially on X11, where there was no way around using native X APIs to verify intended behavior. I got rid of that monstrosity soon later - the effort was unnecessary.

You can have the side panel as a separate top-level frameless widget that moves itself so that its top-right corner is aligned with the top-left corner of the content window, and resizes itself vertically to match the vertical size of the content window. You can of course make it slightly shorter (vertically) while still center-aligning it vertically with the content window.

You'd want to capture the resize events of the content window to do this: the side panel should install itself as an event filter for the content window.

You'll want the side panel to be a Qt child of the content window, *but* you *also* need to make it a top-level window, i.e. set the `Qt::Window` flag on it, so that it becomes top-level and not a sub-widget of the content window.